# laravel nova auto populate relation field on create

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Is there any way that can auto populate the relation field?

[Product Sku Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES4iG.png)

The product image is added as a `HasOne` Relation on `ProductSku` Resource

```
HasOne::make('Image', 'image', 'App\Nova\ProductImage')
```

[Create ProductImage Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paJ47.png)

My ProductImage resource fields is like this -

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
           BelongsTo::make('Product', 'product', 'App\Nova\Product'),
           BelongsTo::make('Product Sku', 'sku', 'App\Nova\ProductSku')
                      ->nullable(),
]}
```

Thank You

Comment: I used nova service provider and an observer to manually add the relationship on modification/create